# SQL optimization distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Suppose I have an SQL query using Oracle SQo Server to get the data from the database 
as below

```
select  distinct ORDER_TYPE_name as ORDER_TYPE from 
PRODUCT_MASTER_LIST where PROJECT_ID = 99999
order by  ORDER_TYPE ASC
```

I now have 5000 records with the following order Types:

```
Red
Yellow
Green
Black 
null
Unclassified
```

How to optimise the performance by shortening the query execution time?

Note When I see the execution plan, there are many full access through the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an index on those two columns to prevent table scans. That should bring down the execution time by a significant extent.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ProductMasterList_OrderType 
ON PRODUCT_MASTER_LIST(PROJECT_ID, ORDER_TYPE);
```

Comment: how can we make use of the index to enhance the performance of table scan ?

Comment: The DB query engine will automatically pick the index if present, so application developer need not do anything specific to make use of the index.

Comment: In this sense, creating an additional query columns by using patrition to assign row numbers and select row number as 1 
as below .
row_number() over (partition by ORDER_TYPE_name, project_id order by ORDER_TYPE_name, project_id) as order_index      
.. where order_index  = 1 

Is useless ?

Comment: No, it will still use the index to deduce the results instead of table scan. That's the purpose of the DB query engine to optimize the accesses to disk for executing queries, by considering the presence of indexes, picking the most appropriate one and reduce the overall cost of the query.

Comment: Actually both your suggested solution and mine will generate the same result in the sense that there are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for each group I have mentioned ?

Comment: @Vikdor, what is the difference between creating one index for both columns or separate index for each one ?

Answer (score 1):

I think index on PROJECT_ID could be the right solution. It depends on selectivity of this column.

```
CREATE INDEX PRODUCT_ML_PRODUCT_ID_IDX ON PRODUCT_MASTER_LIST(PRODUCT_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to run the query often create a **bind variable** , this will DRASTICALLY increase performance.

Example:

```
create or replace procedure dsal(p_empno in number)
as
  begin
    update emp
    set sal=sal*2
    where empno = p_empno;
    commit;
  end;
/
```

In addition create an **index** on the columns you intend to query.

```
CREATE INDEX 
   ix_emp_01 
ON 
   emp (deptno) 
TABLESPACE 
   index_tbs;
```

*Note the TABLESPACE clause is optional*

Comment: And I don't need to modify the SQL ?